# Hive nested query

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have the following table `Emp` in hive consisting of employee along with their Supervisor's of a particular Company. As we know that the Supervisor's are also the employee and even they have a Supervisor above them.

```
employee,Supervisor
a,b
b,c
c,d
d,e
```

I need to write a hive query to find out the supervisor of employee (a) i.e (b) and Supervisor of (b) i.e (c).
I tried using the below query but it throw's an error.

```
select *
from Emp
where employee = (select Supervisor from Emp where employee = "a");
```

Can anyone help me out with this

Comment: What error is the query returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect this query to work:

```
select e.*
from Emp e
where e.employee = (select e2.Supervisor from Emp e2 where e2.employee = 'a');
```

(The only real change are the single quotes for the string constant.)

If Hive has a limitation on subqueries in the `WHERE` clause, just use a `JOIN`:

```
select s.*
from Emp s join
     Emp e
     on s.employee = e.supervisor
where e.employee = 'a';
```